# Suddenly, 12.04 is muted

Tags: sound

Before shutting down last time, I was hearing songs on VLC. Now after rebooting, suddenly my system is muted. When I took "sound settings", all the controls there are deactivated (as in gray and I'm not able to click anything). When I tried opening vlc again, it said :

Audio output failed:
The audio device "default" could not be used:
Device or resource busy.

I'm using 12.04, Gnome classic.

How can I get sound back on my system?

Comment: ... obviously you have rebooted again to check? We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: Silly me. Reboot did the trick.