# I have sound, but volume bar is "inactive" and I can't use volume shortcuts

Tags: 12.04, sound

I just upgraded to 12.04
I have sound. Using headphones also mutes the speaks. So far so good.

I can't use my shortcuts to control volume anymore. It's usually Fn + Left Arrow and Fn + Right Arrow.

In top right corner, the volume bar looks like the volume is all down. Clicking on it, I can go to Sound Settings... and it seems I can't use that application. It opens, but I can't click on anything and basically there is nothing to click on. It's greyed out with no information.

What do I do?
I can control volume through Gnome Alsamixer... or whatever player I play music from (so it seems. I tried Rythmbox... and youtube). But it still seems the sound application doesn't work.

I've got a lenovo U350.

Comment: I had this problem. A reboot worked for me. http://askubuntu.com/questions/130696/suddenly-12-04-is-muted

Comment: Mh, a reboot doesn't work for me, sadly :/
...I don't even know where to look for the problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try killing and restarting pulseaudio, do some /tmp cleaning too.
Open terminal and type switch to root using "sudo su" and then do the following:

killall pulseaudio -KILL

rm -rf /tmp/pulse-*

Exit root by pressing CTRL+D and restart pulseaudio by typing: pulseaudio -D

Comment: I don't have pulseaudio installed, it seems.

but the weirdest thing happened. I turned on my laptop and the sound icon in the top bar was there, still I couldn't use my hotkeys. BUT after a restart of the system it didn't work again.

I've got no idea what's up.

Comment: had the same problem and that worked for me

Comment: NEW INFORMATION!!!

Help! I still have sound issues, but I realise now that the big issue is that I DON'T have any sound when my laptop is running on battery!!!! Running "gstreamer properties" in the terminal I get to choose default output device. When plugged in a socket I get to choose between HDMI 0 and Conexant Analog. Conexant Analog gives me sound. When on battery I can only choose HDMI 0 (= no sound).

Any ideas what to do?